# how to make a tar file backup of a directory in python

Tags: python, recursion, backup

**What I'm trying to do**: I'm trying to make a *recursive* `.tar` file backup of the directory this python script is run in.

**What I currently have:**

```
import os
import zipfile
import datetime
import tarfile
datetime = str( datetime.datetime.now() )
def zipdir(path, zip):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))
backupdir = raw_input('Which directory should we backup to? \n')
if backupdir :
    try:
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('DrupalInstanceBackup'+datetime+'.zip', mode='w')
        zipdir('/Users/localuser/Downloads/backup', zipf)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    finally:
        zipf.close()
```

**What it currently does:**
It makes a .zip backup, but when extracted it doesn't show any files.

**What Im trying to do:**
Can someone help me make this script recursively backup a directory and create a `.tar` archive of the directory and its files in a recursive manner?

Thank you

Comment: A [tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) is very different to a [zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29), you realise? Which do you want? How are you examining the output file?

Comment: A tar file, as it will be stored on a linux server. I am extracting the .zip file currently on my local workstation

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The good news is that [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.add) supports recursively adding members any work.

```
with tarfile.open(archive_name + '.tar.gz', mode='w:gz') as archive:
    archive.add('/Users/localuser/Downloads/backup', recursive=True)
```

`recursive=True` is the default, so you can omit it.

Comment: Does this tar the files of the directory the script is in?

Comment: I think you figured it out, but it will tar files of directories you add with `archive.add`.

Comment: If you want to put all files from source dir without maintaining the complete dir structure, then you can pass `arcname=''`